# A UFD for which the related formal power series ring is not a UFD

Tags: commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains, formal-power-series

I know that the proposition
$$ A \text{ is a UFD } \Rightarrow A[[X]] \text{ is a UFD }$$
is false.

Wikipedia states that if $B=K[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^3+z^7)$ then $A=B_{(x,y,z)}$ is a counterexample, but I can't show that $A$ is a UFD and $A[[X]]$ isn't.

Are there other known counterexample?

Comment: There is a counterexample by Samuel, with $A$ being of characteristic $2$, see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDEQFjACahUKEwjqtcrN09jHAhWF8nIKHeJ7AQE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.maa.org%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fpdf%2Fupload_library%2F22%2FFord%2FPierreSamuel.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE60sZvcVZ7ebIF2YWB31DBT13VmA) , reference [7].