# When is $\dfrac{k[x,y,z]}{(x^a +y^b+z^c)} $ a unique factorization domain?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, unique-factorization-domains, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Let $a,b,c$ be relatively prime positive integers. Then, is $\dfrac{k[x,y,z]}{(x^a +y^b+z^c)} $ a UFD?

This question is motivated from [$(K[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^3+z^7))_{(x,y,z)}$ is a UFD.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424190/kx-y-z-x2y3z7-x-y-z-is-a-ufd), however I do not know how to make a general argument work.

Further thoughts: I can easily see that the ring is a normal domain (it is Cohen-Macaulay and also regular in co-dimension $1$ by calculating the Jacobian). So I would be done if I can show the divisor class group is $0$.

Please help.

Comment: Questions about the class group are usually more arithmetic than geometric in nature (and thus of a different difficulty). In your case, if you localize or complete at the homogeneous maximal ideal, then there is the classic Andreotti-Salmon theorem, which tells you that $k[[x,y,z]]/(f)$ is a UFD iff $f$ is irreducible and not the determinant of a square matrix (of size $> 1$) with entries in $(x,y,z)$