# Factorization of infinite polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, power-series

Does the fundamental theorem of algebra apply for infinite polynomials as well? I haven't studied complex analysis so i'm not asking for a proof just an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by an infinite polynomial?  Do you mean a convergent power series in one variable?

Comment: Yes, such as the taylor series for sin(x) for an example.

Comment: Is infinite polynomial incorrect terminology?

Comment: In which case the answer is probably "no"; I say probably because you haven't told us exactly what you had in mind for such a version of the Fundamental  Theorem of Algebra.

Comment: Yeah, if by fundamental theorem of algebra you mean every power series has a root, then the answer is no since $e^x$ has no root.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem

Comment: @David Yes, it is incorrect. Power series would be correct, and the FTA cannot apply to that, or to anything else, unless we first define what does "a root" of that is and what "its degree" is.

Comment: @CountIblis while you and I both know that it is relevant, that's hardly useful for someone who have not studied any complex analysis.

Comment: I appreciate the responses, thank you.

Comment: Notice that $A$ UFD doesn't imply $A[[X]]$ UFD, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418478/a-ufd-for-which-the-related-formal-power-series-ring-is-not-a-ufd.

Comment: I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Although I think the theorem "Any coercive infinite power series with infinite convergence radius has a root". Indeed assume $f$ is such a power series, and it has no roots. In particular $0$ isn't a root, and thus $1/f$ is a power series as well, with infinite convergence radius. As $f$ is coercive, $1/f$ is bounded, which implies that it is constant (Liouville's theorem), which contradicts the fact that $f$ is coercive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, we need to talk about what kind of "infinite polynomials" (called *power series*) we want to talk about. Many of them do not converge outside of the point $x=0$, even though algebraically they are distinct looking expressions. For instance $\sum n!x^n$ and $\sum n!^2x^n$ are distinct *formal* power series but they both define the same function in the complex plane - namely  the constant zero function whose domain is only $\{0\}$.

At the other extreme are *entire* functions. These functions may be defined by a formal power series (in a complex variable) which converges for all values in the plane. Let's discuss these.

Right off the bat we have an issue: the exponential function $\exp(z)$ has no zeros, and we may use it to create an infinite family of distinct entire functions each having no zeros, namely the entire functions of the form $\exp g(z)$ (where $g(z)$ is also entire).

There are all invertible - we can think of them as "units" (multiplicatively invertible elements) in the "ring" of all meromorphic functions defined on the complex plane. (A *ring* is an algebraic structure where you have addition and multiplication with the usual properties like distributivity.) So we can think of these as like the "leading coefficients" of a polynomial - thinks we can factor out and then put in front of the rest of the factorization.

If the zeros of an entire function $f(z)$ are given by some set $\Lambda=\{\lambda\}$, then we can't use

$$ \prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}(z-\lambda)$$

because this product never converges. (Its partial products could converge to zero if $z=\lambda$ for some $\lambda\in\Lambda$, but many sources call that a divergent infinite product. And otherwise the partial products do not converge to any limit.) One way to fix this would be to *normalize*; consider

$$ \prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\left(1-\frac{z}{\lambda}\right).$$

If the magnitudes $|\lambda|$ grow fast enough, the factors of this product might tend to $1$ fast enough for this infinite product to converge. This introduces another small glitch though: what if $\lambda=0$ is a zero of $f(z)$? Well, then let's just put $z^m$ in front of the factorization for some multiplicity $m$, which solves that problem.

Unfortunately, the sizes $|\lambda|$ may not grow fast enough. This can be fixed with yet another kind of normalizing factor, but it is not so obvious this time. Define the new factors

$$ E_n(z)=(1-z)\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{z^n}{n}\right). $$

Note that $z+z^2/2+\cdots+z^n/n$ is the $n$th partial sum of the Mercator series for $-\ln(1-z)$, so in fact we have $E_n(z)\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$. (Use the convention $E_0(z)=1-z$, the original.)

Then the **Weierstrass factorization theorem** says we can factor $f(z)$ as

$$ f(z)=z^m e^{\,\large g(z)}\prod_{\lambda\in \Lambda} E_{n(\lambda)}\left(\frac{z}{\lambda}\right) $$

for some multiplicity $m$, entire function $g(z)$, and whole numbers $n(\lambda)$.

The factorization is clearly not unique. For instance, one could replace $g(z)$ with $g(z)+2\pi i$ without affecting $f(z)$. Also, one could replace any instance of $E_n(z/\lambda)$ with $E_{n+1}(n/\lambda)$ as long as one subtracts $(z/\lambda)^{n+1}/(n+1)$ from $g(z)$ and this would not change $f(z)$.

Comment: I think this hardly addresses the question, and it's way too wordy and advanced for the OP's level, and deviated from what the OP asked.

Comment: This is a bit much for me at the moment. I'll save this and have look at it when i'm more familiar with the things you wrote about. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DonAntonio Weierstrass factorization for power series that define entire functions is the generalization of factorization of polynomials. I sincerely can't imagine how you consider this to "hardly address the question" or "deviate from what the OP asked." I totally agree it's too advanced for OP's level, but it's not my fault the answer to OP's question is beyond their background to understand, and this answer is useful to other readers that get here who do have sufficient background.