# UFD such that power series are not

Tags: commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains, regular-rings

In Matsumura's ''Commutative ring theory'' he proves the folowing: If $A$ is a regular UFD, the ring of formal series $A[\![ X ]\!]$ is a UFD (page $165$). Just below he says that we can't drop regularity from the hypotesis, whitout giving any counterexample. Is there a non-insane example of UFD $A$ such that $A[\![X]\!]$ is not?

Being a bit optimistic, is true that for every non-regular UFD $A$ the ring $A[\![X]\!]$ is not a UFD?

Comment: A duplicate of the first half is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1418478/29335) but the second half stands .

Answer (score 1):

The wiki page on UFDs offers this example:

Let $R$ be $k[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^3+z^7)$ localized at $(x,y,z)$.  Then $R$ is a UFD but $R[[X]]$ is not.

---

Update: looking through the links that we've found since I posted this, there's a reference to

> [Samuel, Pierre. "On unique factorization domains." Illinois Journal of Mathematics 5.1 (1961): 1-17.](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810135855/https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ecurtis/Samuel-UFDs.pdf)

Which uses this example but also demands $k$ is a perfect field of characteristic $2$.  Even then, the reasoning is *quite* involved and probably too much for a solution here. Currently the paper is open to all, so it will have to do.

That was the early days of the example, so perhaps someone has found a more streamlined explanation since then.

Comment: I would like to piece together a self-contained explanation in a community wiki, because I do not know all the details.

Comment: There is some material about the first claim [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424190/).